# Mask not moving with strip in vse properly

Tags: video-sequence-editor, masking

How do I get my mask and its keyframes to move with the strip as I move it across the timeline?

I Think there is some kind of bug because I have 2 projects open and both are acting differently when the same settings are used, and both are different than I remember all my other projects functioning. So if someone can explain/compare the generic case so I have that as a baseline that might help me.

In the generic:
In a new project. Let's say I Insert a colour strip. Starting at frame 0 I make a mask of a circle that is keyframed to expand and grow larger over 10 frames. I set the mask's start point to 0 in the top N option. I apply the mask to the strip itself under modifiers->mask. I stick with relative mask. I can then move the mask around the vse timeline and have the animation, as it was playing in its original frame position, being respected. If I go absolute mask, its simply stuck in the last or first keyframe's original frame position, depending which its closest to in the timeline.

I have another project and the relative mask isn't working at all on it though. Only Absolute mask works, setting the start frame to 0 since I want it working at the start of the strip. Normally, this would work for the strip even if I move it around the timeline. But for some reason its not on this project or the generic one. Something weird is happening. It was working when I moved the mask around the timeline, then I applied a transform strip and everything, t using transform tools addon, went screwy. However it could have been a case of it giving false information as I can't remember if I refreshed the sequencer after moving it around or not. I'm of the mindset where it was working properly though as this is the method I remember doing with all my other projects without problem. So I'm inclined to believe pressing T and getting the transform strip on there messed something up. But I did the generic case in a new project and that's completely different than anything I remember about masking. I'm noticing tons of inconsistencies, are there any known bugs that might explain any of this? I just want a solution at this point.

Comment: Which Blender version are you using? What transform tools addon? I just transformed a masked strip in Blender 2.79 without any troubles: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5895/

Comment: 2.79b. The original transform tools 1.0 kgeok, not any of the forked versions.

Comment: So this is the exact same as what I experienced when I also did a new project. So if that's the baseline..hmm. something screwy in my other project

Comment: What type of strip are you using in your other project (video, image, scene, meta)? Are you using a proxy strip? What happens when you just add a normal transform modifier without using kgeogeo's addon? Edit: is "Image Offset" enabled on this strip when you're adding the transform modifier?

Comment: So I did the moving circle thing on a colour strip in the problem project, and it worked correctly. The problem seems specific to the strip type in question, which actually makes alot of sense in this case. It's a h.264 mkv video with a speed control of 0.5 applied (use as speed) and the audio file, enclosed together as a meta strip. I've had alot of weirdness happen when speed control is involved, its probably related to that.

Comment: I applied the mask straight to the meta strip, I can try applying it to the speed control within or some other setting within perhaps. I swear I remember absolute masks functioning the way the relatives ones are.....I have no idea why its the opposite now, but maybe I never moved them from the position i made the masks for originally

Comment: I have no idea what starting position the relative mask is referencing. I can't get the relative mask to work 'anywhere' in the vse timeline. Only absolute is working at the point of creation so long as I set the start value to 0. I checked the dope sheet to see better what frames the keyframes are, but its not working even if I position it and assign the start value properly as I would in the "baseline example" we went through.

Comment: "I've had alot of weirdness happen when speed control is involved, its probably related to that." -- Your best bet may be to pre-render out this segment, then apply your mask to the rendered image sequence instead of dealing with the hassle of using a metastrip and speed modifier.

Comment: I can move the mask around the timeline with absolute mask, so long as I enter the start point as the difference between the original position and the new one. But mask start points can only be positive...and not negative, so its only allowing it to move in a singular direction in the timeline. To the left in this case. Better way is using the dopesheet and moving the keyframes to the new location, this allows it to work via absolute mask. It's like moving 2 strips to get 1 action done tho, not very ideal.